# Sorting data based on column entries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe, text

I have a text file containing two column lets say col1 and col2.

```
col1     Col2
A20      A19
A120     A117
A120     A118
A120     B19
A120     B20

.
.
.
B40      A205
```

and so on. 
I want to sort the above columns such that it gives me only those entries which have A and B side by side like:

```
col1     col2
A120     B20 
B40      A205
```

I've tried using pd.DataFrame.sort but it doesn't return the required output. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [indexing by `str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for check if not equal first 2 characters:

```
df = df[df['col1'].str[0] != df['Col2'].str[0]]
print (df)
   col1  Col2
3  A120   B19
4  A120   B20
5   B40  A205
```

If possible multiple starting letters and need test only `A` and `B`:

```
print (df)
   col1  Col2
0   A20   C19 <-changed sample data
1  A120  A117
2  A120  A118
3  A120   B19
4  A120   B20
5   B40  A205

a = df['col1'].str[0]
b = df['Col2'].str[0]
m1 = a.isin(['A','B'])
m2 = b.isin(['A','B'])
m3 = a != b

df = df[m1 & m2 & m3]
print (df)
   col1  Col2
3  A120   B19
4  A120   B20
5   B40  A205
```

Comment: Thank for the quick reply @jezrael, it did help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey jezreal, please check out my new question and do comment on it.

Comment: @Dustrokes - It is on hold, so cannot answer. But in question missing some sample data, need [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).